# How do I remove extra noise from word documents?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2007

I am reading a Microsoft word document 2007 and I keep seeing all this extra noise in the document.

For example:

1. Instead of seeing a link to google, i will see: {HYPERLINK http://www.google.com}
2. Instead of seeing table of contents, i will see {TOC \0 1-2}

Any idea whats going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have field codes visible. To toggle their visibility for the whole document, press <kbd>alt + F9</kbd>. To just toggle one at the time, click in one and press <kbd>shift + F9</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

Try [this tip](http://www.digwin.com/how-to-get-rid-of-the-hyperlink-display-n-word-2007)

> Use <kbd>Alt+F9</kbd> to toggle between the hypelink display and normal view.
>   thats easiest!
>
> Alternatively, you see this settings
>   in "Word options" under office button
>   on the top left corner of the word,
>   then select "Advanced" and keep
>   scrolling down to the area until you
>   see "Show document content" and turn
>   off the setting named:- "Show field
>   codes instead of their values"